# What is the most accurate rendition of the "handling machine?"

Tags: war-of-the-worlds

Ive seen so many, from Jeff Wayne's, to Pengradon's, to the tripod handling machine hyrbids from Speiberg's 2005 version. but what is the most accurate rendition, was there a picture from the 1906 novel where this sketch of a tripod comes from? By accurate i mean closest to the description in the novel, or (like to tripod below) approved by Mr Wells himself. [image]

Comment: "What is "The Handling Machine"?  The illustration looks like a Martian tripod from H.G. Wells's The War of the Worlds (1897), not from any 1906 novel.

Comment: i was just using the picture to ask if there was a handling machine in the same image group. and a handling machine is according to the War Of The Worlds Wiki "The Handling-Machine is a machine created by the Martians and used during their invasion of earth. It has 5 legs and an appearance that resembles a mix between a metallic spider and a crab, with tentacles and extendeble robotic arms. It is pretty short in height, in fact it is only slightly taller than a human."

Comment: i might add, the 1897 sketches werent liked by Wells <img src="https://www.newstatesman.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/06/war_of_the_worlds_pg_141-scaled.jpg" alt="Aliens in Aldershot: why you should catch up on Radio 4&#39;s War of the Worlds"/>

Comment: [Wells himself approved of these incredible drawings, praising them before their publication and saying, “Alvim Corrêa did more for my work with his brush than I with my pen.”](https://www.openculture.com/2015/09/the-first-illustrations-of-h-g-wells-war-of-the-worlds.html)

Comment: sir, if you didnt read correctly "I might add, the 1897 sketches werent liked by wells" you showed me the 1906 sketches, one of which is in my question. if you were replying to the other person, i agree.

Comment: How would one know which sketch is the "most accurate"? Do you have a description from the original novel? Can you [edit] your question to define these criteria?

Comment: @Valorum I think the image you linked to gives the answer. There are several types of machines, one a tripod with a spherical body and one woth the handling machine's 5 limbs and a conical "hat".

Comment: There are 'fighting machines' and 'handling machines'. I have been working on sketches last year, exactly because most illustrations have disregarded large parts of the written descriptions.